# Opening a file on my Mac, using Python, permission denied

Tags: python-3.x, macos

I’m having trouble opening a file on my Mac using Python.

I get an error that I don’t have permission to open the file.  Under ‘get info’ I have read and write permission.

```
file=open(‘/Users/me/Desktop/hello.rtf’)
```

Comment: “I have read and write permission.” But “I” am not what is running the script.

Comment: All right, that makes sense now.  I have it running through my Terminal, successfully.